# Traffic Performance Testing Webpages Under Specified Conditions

Tags: http, load-balancing, performance-testing, traffic-measurement

As the title implies, I would like to be able to simulate traffic to a collection of webpages that I have created for loadbalancing and bottleneck issues. I would like to mimic typical HTTP requests relative to the upload/download speed of the user. Furthermore, I would like to be able to perform extreme tests assuming a certain amount of storage and bandwidth on a server(s).

How I should go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at Apache Flood: hhttp://httpd.apache.org/test/flood/

Good description: http://www.clove.org/flood-presentation/flood.pdf